# An indicator of a planar subset as an element of a tensor product

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Denote $I=(0, 1)$, and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $I$. Does there exist a function $f$ on $I\times I$ viewed as an element of the space $L^\infty(\mu\times\mu)$ such that 
$$
f^2=f
$$
(that is, $f$ takes values 0 and 1);
$$
f(x, y)+f(y, x)=1
$$
(that is, if $f(x, y)=0$ then $f(y, x)=1$, and vice versa);
and $f$ admits a representation
$$
f(x, y)=\int_I g_t(x)\cdot h_t(y)\,dt
$$
(which in particular contains representations as sums $\sum_k g_k(x)\cdot h_k(y)$) with
$$
\int_I \|g_t\|_\infty\cdot \|h_t\|_\infty\,dt<\infty,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ stands for the norm in the space $L^\infty(\mu)$?

**Remark** (update): If we replace the $L^\infty$-norms by the $L^2$-norms in the last formula, we obtain the condition for the integral operator on $L^2(\mu)$ with kernel $f$ to belong to the trace class. Observe that this operator belongs to the Hilbert-Schmidt class for any kernel $f$ satisfying the above properties because $f$ is square-summable.

Update No.2. The integral operator whose kernel is the indicator of the triangle $\{x<y\}$ is not of trace class. (Proof: If it is of trace class, then so is the integral operator whose kernel is the indicator of the rhombus, but [this is not true](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/183004/what-happens-if-we-rotate-the-kernel-of-an-integral-operator/183061#183061).) Therefore, the set $\{f=1\}$ must be very complicated near the diagonal: no subset of $I$ can give us a 'triangular' structure of $f$ even after an arbitrary rearrangement.

Comment: Doesn't a "triangle" function defined by $f(x,y) = 1$ iff $x \leq y$ work ? It satisfies obviously the two first conditions and regarding the third, you may write $f$ as a series of "rectangular" functions, simply tiling the support of $f$ by rectangles.

Comment: I think it does not work, the norm will be infinite.

Comment: Hm, indeed, you're right.

Comment: That is why I believe that the answer is negative; nevertheless, I have no proof, and there is a chance that the function may exist.

Comment: So that's where your motivation comes from ? I suggest you add it somewhere in the description, it never hurts to provide some context, even if it eventually turns out to be irrelevant.

Comment: I have not thought about this properly but this is very reminiscent of two things (1) discussion of idempotent Schur multipliers (2) work of Peller involving functions that are representable by some kind of continuous analogue of $L^\infty \hat{\otimes} L^\infty$. Are these relevant to the original motivation?

Comment: Yes, this all is very close to theory of double operator integrals, which in fact is just a special interpretation of perturbations of selfadjoint operators or commutators that generalize the difference. This also gives us a path to many other topics from operator theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am not sure, but let me try to prove that the answer is negative.

The idea is to prove that any function $f(x,y)$ given by $\int g_t(x)h_t(y)dt$ is continuous with respect to appropriate admissible metric, where admissible means ``separable on the set of full measure.'' Namely, for any $x$ define $F_x(t)=g_t(x)\|h_t(y)\|_{\infty}$. For any $x$ we get a function $F_x(t)$ in (the unit ball of) $L^1(I)$. Thus the pushforward of the metric in $L^1(I)$: $\rho(x_1,x_2):=\|F_{x_1}-F_{x_2}\|_{L^1(I)}$ defines an admissible metric on $I$. Define analogous metric for $y$'s. Next, sum they up and we get still admissible metric on $I$ which we denote $\rho$ too. Note that $f(x,y)$ is continuous and even 1-Lipschitz in variable $x$ in our metric $\rho$. Analogously for $y$. Note that what we actually use is that $\int |g_t(x)|\cdot \|h_t(y)\|_{\infty} dt<\infty$ for any $x$ and viceversa, this is bit weaker than your condition.

Now consider the metric measure space $(I,\mu,\rho)$. Since $(I,\rho)$ is separable, there exists a ball $B(x_0,1/10)$ of radius $1/10$ which has positive measure. Thus $|f(x,y)-f(y,x)|\leq 4/10$ for almost all $x,y$ in this ball. This is impossible by the very definition of $f$.

The above argument is essentially borrowed from http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/1410.0898 and I am glad if our theory may be helpful.

Comment: Fedor, many thanks! I will get into all details carefully and I hope I will accept your answer: for the first look at it, everything seems to be nice. Do you think this proof can be strengthened to cover the $L^2$-norms in place of $L^\infty$-norms (see my 'update' no.1)?

Comment: @limanac Kernels of nuclear (trace class $S^1$) operators are also always virtually continuous. The proof may be found in the reference above.